# Как сделать 2-уровневый генератор моделей продукции?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

1. Есть каталог продукции в [Google Таблице](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EPK-lB6RBxgmmOm6tUsD-a956wEAvT2kRK5VXaar_G4/edit?usp=sharing), где у каждого продукта указаны два списка модификаторов "gen1" и "gen2" через ";".

[image: Каталог]

2. Нужно получить таблицу с теми же колонками, что и в каталоге, но чтобы "gen1" и "gen2" были перемножены на соответствующие строки продукции
3. Сначала я “name” множу на все значения в ячейках колонки "gen1" через “;”

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(ЕСЛИ(ЕТЕКСТ(SPLIT(C3:C101; "; "));(B3:B101&"; "&(SPLIT(C3:C101; "; ")));"")))
```

[image: Модификации первого уровня]

4. Потом полученный результат свожу в одну колонку

```
=SORT({'gen 1'!E3:E20;'gen 1'!F3:F20;'gen 1'!G3:G20};1;ЛОЖЬ)
```

5. Подбираю соответствующий каждому модификатор "gen2"

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ВПР(ЛЕВСИМВ(B3:B101; НАЙТИ(";";B3:B101)-1);'Каталог'!C:E;3))
```

6. Пытаюсь помножить на "gen2" как в 3ем пункте, **!!! и ничего не выдаёт, и ошибок не пишет**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(ЕСЛИ(ЕТЕКСТ(SPLIT(C3:C101; "; "));(B3:B101&"; "&(SPLIT(C3:C101; "; ")));"")))
```

[image: Модификации второго уровня]

Главная проблема: Я не могу сгенерировать второй уровень модификаций.

Вторая проблема: Моя конструкция слишком громоздкая, может её легче решить через script?

[Пример Таблицы](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EPK-lB6RBxgmmOm6tUsD-a956wEAvT2kRK5VXaar_G4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Таблицу пошарьте.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант,

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(
  QUERY(
    FLATTEN(QUERY(
      FLATTEN(C2:C4 & "-" &  SPLIT(D2:D4;";"));
      "where Col1 matches '.*\-.+'")&
        "-"&
          SPLIT(
            VLOOKUP(
              REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(
                  FLATTEN(C2:C4 & "-" &  SPLIT(D2:D4;";"));
                  "where Col1 matches '.*\-.+'");
                "(.*)\-");
              C2:E4;
              3
            );
          ";"));
    "where Col1 matches '.*\-.*\-.+'");
"-")))
```

Какой бы разрушительной для мозга она ни была - работает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрипт, конечно, болеелаконичен, но не менее приятен. Плюс, у меня есть подозрения, что на некоторых объемах он просто перестанет работать.

```
function GENERATE(array, gens = [1], separator = ';', trim = false) {
  return array.reduce((p, row) => {
    const gen = {
      "-1": [row]
    };
    gens.forEach((col, i) => {
      gen[`${i}`] = [];
      gen[`${i - 1}`].forEach(subrow => {
        ('' + subrow[col]).split(separator).forEach(v => {
          const line = [...subrow];
          line[col] = trim ? ('' + v).trim() : v;
          gen[`${i}`].push(line);
        });
      });
    });
    p.push(...gen[gens.length - 1]);
    return p;
  }, []);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как водится, в [Таблице](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1glVUsA2gQqWXPi4PLmKGlaIZA1GxtarND5BQ-94R1nQ/edit?usp=sharing) приведены примеры пошаговой формулы и вызов скрипта из редактора.

Comment: Вариант с формулой корректно работает только если 17 исходных позиции, если больше то результат неверный
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EPK-lB6RBxgmmOm6tUsD-a956wEAvT2kRK5VXaar_G4/edit#gid=596721932
Пока остановился на варианте со скриптом, он работает на 1000 исходных позициях

Comment: Да, скорее всего формула пустые не съест. Надо добавлять разделитель или проверку. Но она уже и так немаленькая. Нужно искать подход.